# postfix[error] :Sender address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table

Tags: postfix, email-server, odoo

I install an application, that it needed smtp information for sending mail, I provide smtp user, password and host for that application, but when it tried to send mail this error had occurred in the application:

`"SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'ash.mavi@gmail.com': (550, '5.1.0  <bounce-14-res.users-5@aaslaam.com>: Sender address rejected: User  unknown in virtual mailbox table')} "`.

what should I do?

mail server log:

```
Apr 29 13:41:41 ns3 postfix/smtpd[30281]: connect from unknown[xx.xx.xx.xx]
Apr 29 13:41:41 ns3 postfix/smtpd[30281]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[xx.xx.xx.xx]: 550 5.1.0 <bounce-15-res.users-5@aaslaam.com>: Sender address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<bounce-15-res.users-5@aaslaam.com> to=<ash.mavi@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<ns1.webmart.com>
```

If you need to know more information, let me know.

Comment: Check your postfix logs, but thereis two spaces between "User" and "unknown", so there is no user provided to the MTA, and it reject your mail

Comment: I placed server log corresponding to this error.

Comment: Are you using SRS? Also, since the email is from your domain (possibly) but to an external domain (gmail) it's normal that you wouldn't allow relaying from `ns1.webmart.com`

Comment: I don't know SRS, I simply install and configure postfix with installing iredmail. How can I found whether I using SRS or not?

Comment: Don't worry about it. First, who is it sending that mail, second, is it in your network, third what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: 1-an application from another server.
2-mail server and the application that sends mail are separated.
3- I edit my question, in first paragraph, that I think is your third answer.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now, so basically you're sending from an application, you have three options 1. If the server is in the same network, you could add the IP to `mynetworks`, 2. If you can use SASL authentication, you need to make sure your application is doing it correctly, how do you have `smtpd_sender_restrictions` restrictions set up in your `main.cf` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Postfix rejected unknown senders.
Comment out one line in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

[`#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender)`= yes`

and your problem will be solved.

Comment: This is a serious security risk. If your machine somehow gets hacked, your machine can be turned into a SPAMbot...

Answer (score 0):

If using a file instead of a table, run `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps` after ensuring the target address in in there.

Comment: Can you explain how this will solve the OP's problem, given that there's no indication that Postfix is configured to look in `/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps`?

Answer (score -2):

Please check if the address where are you sending to is written correctly and there are no spelling errors,(space,dot, .etc).